# 404 Error appearing although page exists

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, windows-authentication

My website is redirecting to 404 error page when the page actually does exist. My website is set up so that it uses windows authentication. If the user does not have access, he/she is redirected to a page that tells them they have no access. If the user does have access then it takes them to another page. My website is set up on a 2008 server with IIS 7.5. In the application pool, the identity is set to `LocalSystem`. Under `.NET Authorization Rules`, I have it set to Allow All Users. The default document is Default.aspx, windows authentication is enabled and the rest is disabled, my website was working before I put in the security. I have researched this and I cannot come across anything else I can do. Also, this works when I run it on my local machine and I am using VS 2013.

Comment: Are ALL of the pages on your site returning the 404? Or just some?  And I assume this is happening after deploying to a remote server, and not on your local dev machine?

Comment: This is after deploying to a remote server and it is happening with all the pages. It is pointing to the correct folder.